# How to check quitly if video stream is alive using http

Tags: c#, performance, http, video, stream

I know I can perform a normal HTTP get and check the response but in my case i have some limitations as the **video feed server is only allowing 1 connection at a time**, which mean any HTTP request while watching the video stream on any player will interrupt the main stream and make it stop.

I have tried different headers with the HTTP GET request (AddRange , ReadWriteTimeout) but all were causing the feed to stop playing on any player

I have tried the HEAD request but for some reason its stuck at GetResponse() as it try to download the content which goes into infinity

> var request = WebRequest.Create("http://xyss.ts") as HttpWebRequest;
>   request.Method = "HEAD";
>   var response = request.GetResponse(); //doesn't stop trying to download content
>   request.Abort();
>   response.Close();

Any idea how we can test if the feed still exist without interrupting the main server feed so it doesn't affect any client streaming

Comment: You can't use a second connection to reliably find out what's up with the first connection anyway, even if it were allowed. What's your use case -- why can't whatever is making the first connection deal with connection loss?

Comment: I don't want to see whats happening with the first connection, i want to know whats happening with the source. And whats making the first connection is general video stream player implemented out there and I dont have a control over them.

Comment: This sounds silly, but you could try `POST` (`WebClient.UploadString` is easiest). If the resource exists, the server should respond with a 405 Method Not Allowed. If not, it should give a 404 Not Found. However, this is still no guarantee that the server won't stop playback, it all depends entirely on how the server implements things -- you'd have a better chance of a good answer if you could name make and model. There's also no guarantee that any response *you* get is a good indicator of what clients can expect.

Comment: Surprisingly the 2 web servers i tested returned 200 OK, and also the stream has stopped  the moment I did the request. Seems these video servers are very sensitive (nginx and etc ) again its not my server though so i can't tell whats going on the server

Comment: If you are in control of neither clients nor servers, I'm inclined to say the problem is unsolvable. The server is designed to allow only one connection and apparently it's doing a good (if overzealous) job of that. Verifying if a connection is possible without interrupting an existing one requires the ability to detect an existing connection, which you don't have.